# c# function not updating parameter

Tags: c#

This is a basic c# application but I am quite rusty. I am just going to start with showing you my code

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;


namespace DatabaseAdder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               int RUId = 0;
                    int QuestionId = 0;
                    DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
                    string QuestionWhenAnswered ;
                    string QuestionResponse;
                    int Accepted;
                    string AssignedWorkStation;
                    string CompleteToken;
            try
            {for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

                   QuestionId ++;
                   QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve(QuestionId);

                    Console.WriteLine(i  );
                    Console.WriteLine( QuestionId);

                    Random rand = new Random();

                // Build connection string
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "localhost";   // update me
                builder.UserID = "sa";              // update me
                builder.Password = "Mypassword123";      // update me
                builder.InitialCatalog = "CDA";

                // Connect to SQL
                Console.Write("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {

                    connection.Open();
                    var sql = "INSERT INTO QuestionResponses(RUId, QuestionId,Date,QuestionWhenAnswered,QuestionResponse,Accepted,AssignedWorkStation,CompleteToken)" +
                        " VALUES(@RUId, @QuestionId,@Date,@QuestionWhenAnswered,@QuestionResponse,@Accepted,@AssignedWorkStation,@CompleteToken)";
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RUId", "1" );
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionId",  "1");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionWhenAnswered", "sam");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionResponse", "sam");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accepted", "1");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedWorkStation", "sam"); 
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompleteToken", "sam");

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All done. Press any key to finish...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

      static int  QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve(int questionId)
        {
            if(questionId < 12)
            {
                questionId = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            }
            return questionId;
        }
    }
}
```

The questionincrementinsetsoftwelve is not changing the value when it is called even when I have debugged and can watch that its value is over 12 but it is still not setting this back to 0.

I understand that there is probably something very small I am overlooking so be easy on my ego.

Comment: The method *returns* the new value. You need to do something with that. Such as `QuestionId = QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve(QuestionId)`.

Comment: As Charles says, plus given the function name, you might want to put questionId++ inside the function. Also, shouldn't < be >?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? If your QuestionId was in fact being updated like you hoped (it can't as is) it would never change from 0 as you increase it to 1, pass it into your method, which works out it's less than 12 and then sets it back to 0. In the next iteration the same thing would happen again.

Comment: Get out of the habit of continuing after a `catch` as if nothing went wrong. Something did go wrong, you are not “all done”. `catch` is for **fixing errors** and `WriteLine` does not fix errors. If you can't fix the error then don't `catch`, let the exception raise to something that can fix it. If it can't be fixed then it will be shown on the console, exactly as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bit

```
QuestionId ++;
QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve(QuestionId);
```

Should be

```
QuestionId ++;
QuestionId = QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve(QuestionId);
```

integers are passed by value, not by reference. So a new integer that has the same value as QuestionId is being passed to the method, and that new integer is being returned from it. You have to assign the result. The behavior you are looking for can be achieved by using the `ref` keyword but isn't needed so long as we assign the result.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `QuestionIncrementInSetsOfTwelve()` a value. It's not updating the parameter, it's taking it in, doing "stuff," and returning a new value.

If you want to alter the parameter passed in, use the `ref` keyword.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Example from microsoft:

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
// Output: 45
```

Notice how this returns nothing? It updates the argument passed in, because it was passed by `ref`.