# No increase in value c#

Tags: c#

I decided to write here, because the Russian Internet really does not like newcomers
For some reason, the program does not increase the values of the variables "sea", "war", "government".
Can you please tell me what this might be related to?

```cs
namespace Prokachka
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int war = 0;
        private int sea = 0; 
        private int goverment = 0;
        int upgradeOchki = 5;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Prockachka(goverment);
            spellLevel();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Prockachka(sea);
            spellLevel();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Prockachka(war);
            spellLevel();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            spellLevel();
            label4.Text += upgradeOchki;
        }

        public void spellLevel()
        {
            label1.Text = "Goverment: " + goverment;
            label2.Text = "Sea: " + sea;
            label3.Text = "War: " + war;
        }

        public void Prockachka(int upgradeSpell)
        {
            if(upgradeOchki > 0)
            {
                upgradeOchki--;
                upgradeSpell++;
                label4.Text ="Очки: " + upgradeOchki;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Prockachka` receives a copy of `government`, and updates that copy, leaving `government` unchanged, etc.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399207/3181933).

Comment: Thanks, @Llama. Sorry for the wrong spelling of the question, this is the first time I am writing here. How say "Thank you" on this site?

Comment: Well, if an answer had been posted that solved your question then you would be able to upvote it and accept it. As I've marked your question as a duplicate, it's not possible. I'd suggest upvoting the answer on the other question that helps you. No need to say thanks though :)